# On pressing delete button in Oracle forms 6i by pressing a button it's showing a strange error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Button has `delete_record` and `commit_form`.

In diagnose error it showing

> Error in query:INSERT INTO user_details(EMPID USERNAME) VALUES
> (:1,:2).
>
> Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into Author Id CAPPS"
> "USER_DETAILS" "PASSWORD").

How this insert query is firing by pressing delete button.
And record is removing from the forms but it's not updated in table.
I think when it comes to commit_form it's showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE_RECORD` built-in does what its name suggests - deletes a record from a block. Subsequent `COMMIT_FORM` commits **all** changes you've made in that form, not only the last action (i.e. deleted record).

It appears that there's a new (or updated) record which doesn't have the PASSWORD value entered, so `COMMIT` - while trying to save changes - fails with ORA-01400 and notifies you that you have to enter a missing value.

Make sure that there are no such rows before committing. One option is to remove the user-defined button and

- delete record using the appropriate toolbar button
- repeat the action (i.e. deleting) if there are more rows that shouldn't be there
- COMMIT using the toolbar button

Comment: I have a tabular display in Oracle forms to display all records...when I press the delete button, it shows the record removed in tabular display(but that doesn't delete the record in table). But when I commit the action that error is showing.(I think it's not committing the delete in database's table)

Comment: Exactly. DELETE_RECORD just removes it from the screen. In order to save changes (i.e. remove it from the database as well), you have to COMMIT, no doubt in that. However, you're **inserting** at the same time, and lack of required column(s) (*password*, in your case), raises the error.